# Cannot link ImageMagick with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, imagemagick, static-libraries

I know this has been asked for *ImageMagick* couple of times and many times for *How to link stuff in VS* but it seems I cannot link *ImageMagick*'s libraries with my program in VS2013!!!

What is wrong with the way i am doing it!?

#### Include Directory Setting

[image]

#### Library Directory Setting

[image]

#### Library Setting

[image]

These codes compile fine under Unix-Like environments, but not windows'.
I have been on this for whole day, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: @dlemstra The common link error, for ImageMagic's unidentified symbols.

Comment: Go to **Build** => **Configuration Manger** and switch **Active solution platform** to *x64*. I'm guessing your project is win32 attempting to link to 64 lib

Comment: Can't upvote emcconville's comment but switching to x64 worked for me (VS2019)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
CORE_RL_MagickCore_.lib
CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib
CORE_RL_MagickWand_.lib
```

Instead. This works in my visual studio 2013.
Other than this I can see no other reason why it shouldn't be working.